# How can KGB officers, born and bred in USSR, speak perfect accentless American English?

Tags: realism, the-americans

I know Matthew Rhys's (who portrays Phillip Jennings) first language is Welsh, and speaks English with a Welsh accent, so he's imitating  the US accent in *The Americans*.  But US-born actors with American English as their mother tongue, portray many KGB spies like

1. his movie and real-time wife, Keri Russell, who portrays Elizabeth Jennings.
2. Frank Langella who portrays their first KGB handler. Margo Martindale who portrays Claudia, the Jennings' second and fifth KGB handler.

The Jennings never lived in the US when they were kids, for in the scene (please edit this if you remember which) where they're checking into their motel, the air conditioner dazzles Elizabeth who remarks the USSR doesn't have these luxuries.

The Jennings are flashed back as  impecunious when they were kids. So they probably didn't learn English diligently until they joined the KGB in their 20s. So it feels unrealistic that these KGB spies could've acquired US English to speak like native speakers. Research on L2 (second language) acquisition doesn't substantiate such success.

Fromkin. [*Linguistics: An Introduction to Linguistic Theory* (2001 1 edn)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0631197117). p 546.

> A strong foreign accent can often persist
> even after years of practice.

Yule. *The Study of Language* (2016 6 ed). p 210. If anyone has the [2020 7 edn](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1108730701), please don't hesitate to edit this.

> Despite the fact that insufficient
> time, focus and incentive undermine many L2 learning attempts, there are some individuals
> who seem to be able to overcome the difficulties and develop an ability to use the
> L2 quite effectively, though not usually sounding like a native speaker.
>       However, even in ideal acquisition situations, very few adults seem to reach nativelike
> proficiency in using an L2. There are individuals who can achieve great expertise
> in the written language, but not the spoken language. One example is Joseph Conrad
> (1857–1924), who wrote novels in English that became classics of English literature, but
> whose English speech retained the strong Polish accent of his L1. This might suggest
> that some features of an L2, such as vocabulary and grammar, are easier to learn than
> others, such as pronunciation. Indeed, without early experience using the sounds and
> intonation of the L2, even highly proficient adult learners are likely to be perceived as
> having an “accent” of some kind.
> [...]
> The optimum age for learning may be during
> the years from about ten to sixteen when the flexibility of our inherent capacity for language
> has not been completely lost, and the maturation of cognitive skills allows a more
> effective analysis of the regular features of the L2 being learned.

Some KGB officers speak accented English like those portrayed by USSR-born actors, like

3. Lev Gorn who portrays Arkady Ivanovich Zotov, the KGB's Rezident at the Soviet embassy.
4. Costa Ronin as Oleg Igorevich Burov, originally the Soviet embassy's Science and Technology officer, a privileged son of a government minister.

Comment: Those selected to be under-cover spies would either have the background or the training to not have a noticeable accent.  If you have a large enough cohort to select from - you can choose those who manage the accent, and reject those who do not.  Perhaps they spent time as children in the USA.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: @iandotkelly Don't my quotes from linguistics textbook counter "the training to not have a noticeable accent"? If this training is possible, then more people would become polyglots.

Comment: @iandotkelly "Perhaps they spent time as children in the USA." I've watched every episode of The Americans, but they never mentioned this?

Comment: Is the childhood back story of every character explained?

Comment: Either (a) they speak with a native American accent because they spent childhood time in the US, (b) they have been trained to speak with an American accent or (c) it's unrealistic.  The fact that actual spies exist who do pass for a native imply (a) or (b) can happen.  Your quotes from a linguistics textbook indicating that it is hard don't really counter that it isn't impossible.  Very few people are given the luxury of long term (i.e. expensive) intensive training.  Actors are for example - and some are excellent.

Comment: @iandotkelly It feels improbable that the series would flashback to their childhood, and never once mention that they grew up in the US when such an upbringing is so relevant. I also edited my post to prove this.

Comment: Maybe they had access to actual Americans while they were learning English (either prisoners or traitors) who taught them how to speak.  Anecdotally, I had a roommate in college who was born and raised in France, and spoke English with a perfect British accent (because her English teachers were British.) She didn't speak it with a French accent, and I doubt she spent any significant effort (over and above the normal effort required to learn a new language, of course.) Which speaks to @iandotkelly's point about choosing those who can drop the accent.

Comment: What's the point of the quotes? None of them claim "no one with an L2 speaks it without an influence from L1". None of them are studies on what percentage of the learner population shows a noticeable accent compared to one of a small region. And you're questioning the ability of the spies to perform one of the basic requirements of being undercover. Might explain the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: No, the quotes do not counter the possibility of someone having a convincing accent. The quotes don’t say it’s impossible and textbooks are not necessarily 100% true. They are written by fallible humans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sort of a joke.

"I am very lucky, because I come from the place where everyone speaks English without an accent, and the farther away from where I live someone comes from, the stronger their accent is.  I'm so lucky to come from the small region where everyone speaks English correctly."

What makes this a joke?

Everybody has an accent.  You don't notice your own accent because to you that is the normal way of speaking English, but you do notice people who speak English with different accents.

So obviously the Russian spies in the show do speak English with an accent, but they studied American English so hard and so long that they speak it with an American accent and not a foreign accent, especially not a Russian accent like native Russian speakers would be expected to have.

The Russian spies would have been trained to speak American English without a strong regional accent, so presumably they would used the accent used by most television performers, the more or less standard American accent.

Comment: Don't my quotes from linguistics textbooks counter "they studied American English so hard and so long that they speak it with an American accent and not a foreign accent"?

Comment: Adding to this: the 2 spies were the elite from a number of candidates in the USSR, they were selected for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that they were graduates of *Vinnytsia*, a [finishing school for undercover 'sleepers' and infiltration agents](https://moscowamerican.com/index.php/KGB_Spy_town) intending to spend time in the US without rousing suspicions. In addition to being given an intensive course in American culture they were also provided with intensive language training to remove accents and prep agents to use contemporary American idioms.

> The motion picture theaters in Winniza show only Hollywood movies and
> the stories sell only U. S. made articles. The students drive Fords or
> Chevrolets by U. S. traffic rules. They study the history of the US.
> in original American school books and they talk about baseball and the
> latest scandals.
>
> **The first stage in the training Is devoted entirely to studies of
> American dialects which they must be able to speak perfectly.**
>
> "The only genuine thing in this American city in the Ukraine is the
> high barbed wire fence that surrounds it," the army journal said.
>
> "The pupils In this spy school are hand picked from the best students
> In Soviet universities. Western Intelligence services estimate the
> number of students at Winniza at between 1.000 and 1,300."
>
> The training goes on for years, "in some cases even 10 years.*' "Then,
> when these agents go to the States—either in a legal way as diplomats
> or In other ways— they are ready at once to fill their mission."
>
> <sub><sup>[Daytona Beach journal - April 13, 1959: Russ Spy Centre is copy of U.S. town](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1873&dat=19590413&id=lqYoAAAAIBAJ&sjid=DcoEAAAAIBAJ&pg=3215,2189473&hl=en)</sup></sub>